# PHP: Get calling referenced array name

Tags: php, function

Supposing the following function and call:

```
function doSomething( &$someArray ) {
    // Do something to $someArray
}

$names=array("John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo");
doSomething($names);
```

Is there any way to get the name of the referenced array (in this case "names") from within the function? I know that I could refactor to add another argument to the function for the name of the array variable, but that is just inviting bugs. The use case is that for each array $someSillyName the function needs to access the database table someSillyName.

Thanks.

Comment: No, there is no way. `$names` is a name *local* to the caller. That information isn't available to the called function, short of reading the source code of the caller...

Comment: As @Borealid said, not with what you've provided there.  Simple arrays do not have a name property that you could access to get that kind of information.  If you passed a class however, you could get the class name - but not the name of the variable even in that case.

Comment: I can see where you're coming from with your use case, but believe me that it's the wrong way to do it. What if you need to fetch two different results and store them in `$names1` and `$names2`? Either your code will break, or you need to bend over backwards to make it work, unnecessarily complicating your code. *That's* a problem leading to bugs.

Comment: Thanks, all. I figured it was worth a shot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this in PHP.

Moreover, you should avoid to use variable names for application logic.  Imagine, someone refactors your $name to something else.. You could amend your array like this:

```
$dbData = array(
    'names' => array("John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo")
);
```

This should also help you in other parts of your application. If you really want to go this way, I'd recommend to create a Class that encapsulates this array and provides stuff like `getDatabaseName();` and `getData();`

Comment: Thank you. I will see about refactoring as such.

Answer (score 4):

No.*
If `"names"` is necessary information for `doSomething` to do its job, pass it as an argument.

<sub>* You could use debug backtracing and lots and lots of introspection, but that's *insane*. Variable names in the caller's scope should have absolutely no influence on anything.</sub>

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was afraid of.

Comment: Reviewing my answers I'd like to add here:
If you need to pass arguments to fulfill a job you have problems in your architecture. This is a common problem of developers from the procedural days. Following this way only adds more arguments when an additional/different task has to be done. In general, if you feel the need to add arguments you should reconsider your objects.
Otherwise you will find yourself lost in a bunch of parameters, IFs and unmaintainable code.